# android edittext onLongPress context menu

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-contextmenu

I want to do the following to enable user to long press on EditText and then show context menu with only the following options (Select, Select All) and then allow the user to select part of text or select all text

I want this to work on OS 2.2 and above

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extend the EditText class. Check out this link:

[Dynamically Modifying Contextual/Long-Press Menu in EditText Based on Position of Long Press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096613/dynamically-modifying-contextual-long-press-menu-in-edittext-based-on-position-o)

This method worked for me to do a similar thing

Answer (score -1):

Simply:

```
EditText text = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.myET);
    text.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

           //my dialog code
            return false;
        }
    });
```