# Can I get/set the position of the first visible letter of TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-widget

Let's say that there is a `TextView` with a large text, inside of a `ScrollView` like below. The TextView's `text` property is:

> The executive Power shall be vested in a President of the United States of America. He shall hold his Office during the Term of four Years, and, together with the Vice President, chosen for the same Term, be elected, as follows ...(continues)...

, so currently, the first visible letter "s" is the 88th letter in the TextView's `text` property. Can I get this number 88? If so, can I also scroll the TextView (or the enclosing ScrollView) so that the first visible letter's index is 88, or at least the 88's letter is at the top visible line?

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636946/get-current-visible-text-in-textview) help?

Comment: @TylerV No, that did not work. However,  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15686638/455796) worked.