# How tot scroll to end of an android TextView?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget

I have a `android.widget.EditText` (in multi line read only mode) in which I display some informations (the left half):

[image]

From time to time additional informations are added to the end of this `android.widget.EditText` and then I would like to scroll to the end of the the field (perhaps only scrolling to the end if already positions at the end which I think is even more user friendly).

Surprisingly I was unable to find any information on cursor and scroll movement in `android.widget.EditText`.

I found [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289575/scroll-textview-to-text-position) but i don't have a `ScrollView` and I wonder why would I want one as a `android.widget.EditText` can handle it own scolling.

Any ideas or insights? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, Casio FX602P was my very first programmable computer!

I am not sure if editView can be made to scroll on its own, but if you envelop a textView with a scrollView and disable the scroll bars you should get what you need.

One other possibility came to my mind; if you use a List instead that would allow not just to scroll but to select the line of code which one wants to edit in the display on the right...

Comment: A List might not be as good s I want the user to be able to copy paste the result for use in other applications. So the extra scroll view might be the only option.

PS: The calculator is available in the market already ;-). I am just adding the final touches for Honeycomb right now. It's GPL as well, you can look at the sources as well of you like.

Comment: It is easy to convert a list into a text, it is just one loop. Actually I would like a real thing, but it is not easy to get it on eBay, everyone wants it!

Comment: Using a `android.widget.ScollView`does work but I found an even easier trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333778/how-tot-scroll-to-end-of-an-android-textview/7345050#7345050

Answer (score 3):

If scrolling to the end is all you want then the following will do:

```
     this.Printout.setText ("");
     this.Printout.append (Service.Get_FP10_Printout ());
```

The trick here: `android.widget.EditText.append` will scroll to the end of the field for you. So I delete the text and then append what I want to display.

If you need any other scrolling then you need to  envelop the `android.widget.TextView` with an `android.widget.ScollView` (as [lumis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562497/lumis) suggested) and use the [trick from Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289575/scroll-textview-to-text-position/5625540#5625540).

Comment: I wonder if it would scroll if you append just a single space or return on the text already in it? Nice thing about the scroll view is that by using a CountDownTimer and scrollTo() you can set your own speed of scrolling.

Comment: With the other calculator (http://my.opera.com/HP-45/blog/2011/03/09/honeycomb-has-arrived) I do add single returns and yes it works as expected. This is how I found out about this behaviour in the first place. However: You then have an empty row at the end of the field.

Comment: I am curious, have you tried to append an empty string: object.append("");

Comment: No I did not. For me there is not difference since the FP10 Simulator keeps the text in a StringBuffer and I always need to set the text in full anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you must wrap the EditText in a ScrollView and control it through it's parent. It was previously possible to simply use EditText.append to accomplish this as indicated by one of the answers [append](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7345050/3259330) here. However google has made all standard EditText's AppCompat now which has changed the behavior of the append function, it no longer scrolls to the end.

I found out the hard way as my app's functionality changed after a compile with the newer API.